# How to update Test Execution status (Pas/Fail) in jira using zapi (rest Api) with protractor framework

Tags: jira-zephyr

How to update Test execution status ( Pass/Fail) in Jira in automatically using protractor framework.

Test management tool used Jira with zephyr plugin.

Any Rest API plugin available? Please provide example.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In order to update the execution status you need to perform a REST call with this details:

Method: PUT

URL: https://{your_company_jira_url}/jira/rest/zapi/latest/execution/{executionId}/execute

Headers:

Content-Type: application/json

And in body specify this JSON:

For PASS:

```
{ "status": 1 }
```

For FAIL:

```
 { "status": 2 }
```

You can find more information (depending of your Zephyr/Jira version) in: https://zfjcloud.docs.apiary.io/#

I hope helps.